# Convert dataframe: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, indexing

Can someone help me, I'm trying to create a dataset and always the same error `only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` for the same code snippet

```
Y = pd.Series(dataset_df['bin'].values.flatten().tolist(), index=X.index).to_frame('bin'))
```

I don't understand why this error occurs. If anyone can explain it to me, thank you in advance.

obs.: the `data` variable is a dataframe, the `FEATURE_COLUMNS` variable is the `data` column (like `feat_mean_frac_close`) and the `daily_vol` variable is float.

```
def create_dataset(data, daily_vol):
    
    TP = 0.01
    SL = - TP

    T, P, X, Y, Y2 = [], [], [], [], []
    TIME = []
    
    for i in daily_vol.index:

        window = data.loc[i][FEATURE_COLUMNS].values

        if np.isnan(window).any():
            continue

        now = data.close[i]
        future_window = data.loc[i:i + timedelta(days=HORIZON)].close

        Ti = daily_vol.loc[i]

        min_ret_situation, take_action, timings = get_meta_barier(future_window, now, Ti, TP, SL, False)

        X.append(window)
        Y.append(min_ret_situation)
        Y2.append(take_action)
        T.append(timings)
        P.append(data.loc[i].close)
        TIME.append(i)
        
    dataset_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(X), columns = [FEATURE_COLUMNS], index = TIME)
    dataset_df['bin'] = np.argmax(Y, axis=1)
    dataset_df['t1'] = pd.Series(dataset_df.index, index = dataset_df.index)
    dataset_df['w'] = 1. / len(Y)

    X = dataset_df[FEATURE_COLUMNS]
    Y = pd.Series(dataset_df['bin'].values.flatten().tolist(), index=X.index).to_frame('bin')
    Y['w'] = 1./Y.shape[0]
    Y['t1'] = pd.Series(Y.index, index = Y.index)
    X.columns = FEATURE_COLUMNS
    
    return X, Y, T, P

from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.strptime('2010-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') # 2017

X, Y, T, P = create_dataset(data[:t], daily_vol[:t])
```

Comment: This isn't a random error. Repeated calls to the same thing won't make it go away! What is `X.index`?  Just one value, or several?

Comment: X.index are several values

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, but my guess is that one input, probably to `Series` is supposed to be a 'scalar' (a single number), but you are instead giving it an array with more than one value.  Test the problem expression one step at a time, till you get a minimal expression that generates the error.

Comment: You included a function, where *dataset_df* is created.
This function however uses some variables of unknown content, so we are not able to reproduce your problem.
Instead of forcing us to "guess" what is the content of used variables, generate *dataset_df* (at least some fragment, leading to your error) and rework your post, putting just this DataFrame.